# How to change the logon accounts for the SQL Server 2008 services

Tags: sql, authentication, accounts

I have a requirement to change the service logon accounts for the SQL server 2008 services through script. I know we can do this manaually using Sql Server Configuration Manager. But i couldnt find a script for achieving this.

Comment: Are you expecting a SQL script?

Answer (score 0):

Found via Google ("change sql 2008 service account programatically"), modifies the account using WMI:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mwories/archive/2006/11/03/wmi_5f00_change_5f00_password.aspx